# Can I turn the water supply to the shower off here (picture)?

Tags: shower, shutoff

I posted earlier about a Ghroe shower faucet that wouldn't turn off. I managed to finally get the handle off and now I am looking at this inside the wall.

The flat head screws that are on the far sides behind this piece in the middle - are those what I should be able to turn to cut the water to this shower? Or is there another way?

My goal here is not to repair this whole thing rather than to see if I can just shut off the water to the shower so I can turn the house water supply back on and call a plumber during the week for a full repair or replace.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

in the back those slotted things look like shut-off valves to me. try turning them 90 degrees using a flat-bladed screwdriver

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Jasen. I am trying but the will not budge!  I have some "PBBlaster" that I sprayed on and will go back and try in a bit.  I found literature from Grohe about this "Universal Pressure Balance Rough-In Valve" & it says it has built-in Service Stops - I assume thats what those screws are?

Comment: They certainly have the appearance of stop valves, I can see the barrel retaining clip on the right one. Maybe bang the screwdriver with a hammer a little, they might be frozen up by lime scale etc.  also try turning in the opposite direction.  with the slot in-line with the

Comment: One moved! The right one. Now waiting to see if the left frees up. If I turn them a quarter turn - 90 degrees counterclockwise this should shut the water off to the valve, correct?

Comment: Well, finally. After a few hours and some of the skin off my palm...I got the other one. It appears to have stopped the water to the shower once I turn the water on to the house. Thanks for the guidance. Fingers crossed it holds until I can get the plumber here.